# Disable a text edit field in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, disable

I need to disable TextFormField occasionally. I couldn't find a flag in the widget, or the controller to simply make it read-only or disable.
What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Filed https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10645

Comment: For people from google, you can now add a flag on the widget, see my answer.

Comment: @Arash can you change the accepted answer to one of the more recent ones because the framework now supports this

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This isn't a feature that is currently provided by the framework, but you can use a [`FocusScope`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FocusScope-class.html) to prevent a `TextFormField` from requesting focus.

Here's what it looks like when it's disabled.

(with hint text)
[image: empty and readonly]

(with a readonly value)
[image: readonly]

Here's what it looks like when it's enabled.

(with focus)
[image: focused]

(without focus)
[image: editable]

Code for this is below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new HomePage(),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePageState createState() => new HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();
  bool _enabled = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Disabled Text'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: new Icon(Icons.free_breakfast),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _enabled = !_enabled;
          });
        }
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: _enabled ?
          new TextFormField(controller: _controller) :
          new FocusScope(
            node: new FocusScopeNode(),
            child: new TextFormField(
              controller: _controller,
              style: theme.textTheme.subhead.copyWith(
                color: theme.disabledColor,
              ),
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                hintText: _enabled ? 'Type something' : 'You cannot focus me',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: no need to add this?

`FocusScopeNode(canRequestFocus: _enabled, child: .....`

Answer (score 190):

```
TextFormField(
readOnly: true,
)
```

Comment: In order to create a more robust answer, you should add some context of what your code is doing. For more help, see [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's what I looking for, enabled: false makes the suffix iconbutton disabled (I use content_copy icon to copy). But this one works

Comment: There's a problem with readOnly:true - When user selects this control - the blue borders come up - which is basically saying that it's allowing focus to the control.

Comment: I do not like using readOnly: true since, when focusing on the readOnly field, its size is reduced.

Answer (score 182):

There is another way this can be achieved which also does not cause [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13694). Hope this might help someone.

Create `AlwaysDisabledFocusNode` and pass it to the `focusNode` property of a `TextField`.

```
class AlwaysDisabledFocusNode extends FocusNode {
  @override
  bool get hasFocus => false;
}
```

then

```
new TextField(
    enableInteractiveSelection: false, // will disable paste operation
    focusNode: new AlwaysDisabledFocusNode(),
    ...
    ...
)
```

**Update:**
`TextField` now has `enabled` property. Where you can just disable the `TextField` like

```
new TextField(
    enabled: false, 
    ...
    ...
)
```

*Note: This will also disable icon associated with text input.*

Comment: Yes, you can have a TextFormatter that ignore any input (through paste), but return the source to avoid this behaviour :)

Comment: I found a simpler one, in my case I used your solution and just ignored the popup to prompt the paste using `enableInteractiveSelection: false` for the `TextField` ;)

Comment: enable=false; doesn't dispatch onTap() event. I want it disabled and not focusable but I don't want it dead. I want to have control over it. It should still fire onTap() if set. Not even if wrapping it in a GestureDetector. Man this flutter can be disappointing some times...

Comment: @Dpedrinha why not use my first solution,  `AlwaysDisabledFocusNode`?

Comment: @HemanthRaj I tried it too. I don't remember the problem now, but it also prevented some desired behavior.

Comment: `enabled=false` also disables scroll, `onTap` and more. `AlwaysDisabledFocusNode` hides text selection (the semi-transparent box you get when long tap to copy the text). I wish a proper readonly option was there.

Answer (score 88):

`TextField` and `TextFormField` both have an argument called `enabled`. You can control it using a boolean variable. `enabled=true` means it will act as an editing text field whereas `enabled=false` will disable the `TextField`.

Comment: This is the actual answer.

Comment: It depends on your needs. Both solve the issue but Hemanth Raj solution does not  disable the icon associated with the text input(put some grey color over your accentColor theme) which might tell the user he has nothing to complete (maybe you want the user to click on a modal and complete that field with default values). For just disabling an input Vikas Pandey answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: This is the actual answer!

Comment: the problem with `enabled=false` that it prevents error message appearance

Comment: enabled=false does not do anything

Comment: This is the answer I wanted. Simple and solid

Comment: Best answer: `enabled=false` is more suitable then `readOnly=true`, since the latter doesn't block any interaction whereas `enabled=false`  really disables the `TextField` or `TextFormField`.

Answer (score 32):

Similar to readonly like in html

```
TextField(
    enableInteractiveSelection: false,
    focusNode: FocusNode(),
)
```

This can response to onTap.

---

Similar to disabled like in html

```
TextField(
    enable: false
)
```

This can not response to onTap.

Comment: This is exactly what I need form my calendar input. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

This is another way of somehow disabling a `TextField` but keeping it's functionality. I mean for `onTap` usage

```
TextField(
    enableInteractiveSelection: false,
    onTap: () { FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode()); },
)
```

- `enableInteractiveSelection`

  will disable content selection of `TextField`
- `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());`

  change the focus to an unused focus node

Using this way, you can still touch `TextField` but can't type in it or select it's content. Believe me it's going to be useful sometimes ( datepicker, timepicker, ... ) :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: It's not needed. There's `readOnly` property

Comment: @user1209216 `readOnly` still makes it able to focus thus the blue line and label going up

Answer (score 21):

I have used a combination of *readOnly* and *enableInteractiveSelection* properties to achieve the desired behavior on TextField.

```
TextField(
  readOnly: true,
  enableInteractiveSelection: true,
  onTap: () {
    do_something(),
  },
)
```

With *enableInteractiveSelection* set to *true*, it will allow *onTap()* to function as normal.

Comment: This is the best answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: in onTap function try to use FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(); it will disabled the writting mode

Answer (score 21):

Use `readOnly:true` is correct. But if you still want focus to this text field you can follow below code:

```
TextFormField(
  showCursor: true,//add this line
  readOnly: true
)
```

And if you want hide text pointer (cursor), you need set `enableInteractiveSelection` to `false`.

Answer (score 13):

I tried using FocuseNode(), enabled = false yet not working,
  Instead of that I use a **widget** called *AbsorbPointer*. It's use for preventing a widget from touch or tap, I wrap my TextFormField or other widget inside AbsordPointer Widgets and give a parameter to disable from touch

**Example**

```
AbsorbPointer(
      absorbing: true,  //To disable from touch use false while **true** for otherwise
      child: Your WidgetsName
);
```

Comment: This works for me. The `absorbing` param will default to true so u omit

Answer (score 13):

For that... TextField has two properties:

```
TextField(
          readOnly: true,
          enabled: false,
        )
```

1- If you desire to disable the TextField typing and taping set [enabled: false]

2- If you desire to disable **only** TextField typing set [readOnly: true]

Answer (score 12):

There is now a way to disable `TextField` and `TextFormField`. See github [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/16027).
Use it like this:

```
TextField(enabled: false)
```

Comment: probably best answer, I wonder why it's not up voted

Answer (score 10):

```
TextField
(
   enable: false
)
```

Or

```
TextFormField(
    enable: false
)
```

if you use **InputDecoration** don't forget to set **disabledBorder** like this

```
TextFormField(
      enabled: false,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
        ),
        disabledBorder:  OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.gray),
        ),
        filled: true,
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 9):

It has `enabled` key, this is doing fine for me.

```
TextFormField(
    enabled: false,
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
                    readOnly: true,
                    enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                    onTap: () {
                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `readOnly: true`

```
TextField(
  readOnly: true,
  controller: controller,
  obscureText: obscureText,
  onChanged: (value) {
    onValueChange();
  },
  style: TextStyle(
    color: ColorResource.COLOR_292828,
    fontFamily: Font.AvenirLTProMedium.value,
    fontSize: ScreenUtil().setHeight(Size.FOURTEEN)),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
    hintText: hint,
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
      fontSize: ScreenUtil().setHeight(Size.FOURTEEN),
      color: ColorResource.COLOR_HINT,
      fontFamily: Font.AvenirLTProBook.value)),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove native keyboard then focus TextField programmaticaly (for example, after click emoji button):

```
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(titleFocusNode);
titleFocusNode.consumeKeyboardToken();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me

```
TextField(
          readOnly: true,
         onChanged: (value) { },
        )
```

Answer (score -1):

For that... TextField:

```
TextField(
          readOnly: true,
          enableInteractiveSelection: false,
          enabled: false,
        )
```