# Arithmetic Operations on Textformfields flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I want to disable Rate/kg for writing and give it a value by calculating like this

```
Rate = amount/weight +carriage/weight +unloading/weight
```

I dont know how to perform these operations on text field plz help [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yy8op.jpg)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490622/disable-a-text-edit-field-in-flutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution would be executing calculate method `onChange` of every `TextField`.

Here is the example in which we have three `TextField`, and we want to show sum of first two `TextField` in third `TextField`.

You can disable the `TextField` with `enabled` property or you can use `AbsorbPointer`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StackOverFlow extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StackOverFlowState createState() => _StackOverFlowState();
}

class _StackOverFlowState extends State<StackOverFlow> {
  TextEditingController _firstController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _secondController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _thirdController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: _firstController,
              onChanged: (value) {
                _calculate();
              },
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: _secondController,
              onChanged: (value) {
                _calculate();
              },
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            ),
            AbsorbPointer(
              child: TextField(
                controller: _thirdController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _calculate() {
    if (_firstController.text.trim().isNotEmpty &&
        _secondController.text.trim().isNotEmpty) {
      final firstValue = double.parse(_firstController.text);
      final secondValue = double.parse(_secondController.text);
      _thirdController.text = (firstValue + secondValue).toString();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In-Text widget, You can use the Arithmetic operations like this,

```
Container(
child: Text(
(currentTemp + kelvin).toStringAsFixed(1),
style: TextStyle(
fontSize: 60,
color: Colors.white,
),
),
),
```