# Flutter TextField disable input

Tags: flutter

Can I disable input in `TextField` with open keyboard?

I am trying `TextField` with `readOnly` property, but when I set `readOnly` value `true` my device keyboard hide. I want do this without hidding keyboard

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490622/disable-a-text-edit-field-in-flutter

Answer (score 9):

You can try this

```
TextField(
   readyOnly: true,
   showCursor: true,
   // ...
),
```

Answer (score 2):

As for now, you can do this by adding enabled to your TextField.

```
TextField(
 controller: _controller,
 enabled: false,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is like so.

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget>{
  var tc = TextEditingController();
  var readOnlyText = 'read only';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tc.text = readOnlyText;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
        controller: tc,
        onChanged: (_){
          tc.text = readOnlyText;
          tc.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: tc.text.length));
        },
    );
  }
}
```