# Flutter: disable the user input while data is uploading

Tags: flutter, user-interface

To prevent errors I want to disable the user input while my flutter app is uploading some data to firebase. I already tried IgnorePointer and AbsorbPointer with a boolean which gets updated via setState when the user presses "upload data". But the user can still enter something on the screen.

Is there a way to disable the user input while the data is uploading? After the upload is finished the user will be navigated automatically in the main menu.

Here are some parts of the code:

```
class AddJob extends StatefulWidget {
 AddJob({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 @override
 _AddJobState createState() => _AddJobState();
}

class _AddJobState extends State<AddJob> {
 bool ignoring = false;
 Future<void> addJob() async {
 return showDialog<void>(
    barrierDismissible: true,
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius:       BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
        title: Text('Privat oder Öffentlich?'),
        content: Text(
            'xy'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            child: Text('back'),
          ),
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                setState(() {
                  ignoring = true;
                });

                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 4),
                  content: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      new Text(" Hochladen...")
                    ],
                  ),
                ));

... uploading
  }
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final _picker = ImagePicker();
return IgnorePointer(
  ignoring: ignoring,
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
      if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
        currentFocus.unfocus();
      }
    },
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius:
                BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(15))),
        backgroundColor: blueLayerOne,
        title: Text('create'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline_rounded),
              onPressed: () {
                showInfos();
              }),
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(

...normal screen widgets
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share some code or at least what widgets you are using for user input?

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490622/disable-a-text-edit-field-in-flutter

Comment: @tomerpacific just updated my post above.

Comment: @TobyLoby unfortunately not because I want to disable it for the whole screen not just a for a textField.

Comment: I don't see any form elements here...

Comment: What do you mean? I never mentioned form elements, I meant the disable functionality just for the whole screen, so the user can't tap anywhere on the app while the data ist uploading.

Comment: Wrap it with Stack() create Positioned() Container() with double.infinity heigh, width and show it during upload