# What is Tile in flutter_staggered_grid_view

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use `AlignedGridView` from `flutter_staggered_grid_view` as mentioned in their [Docs](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) -

```
AlignedGridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 4,
  mainAxisSpacing: 4,
  crossAxisSpacing: 4,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Tile(
      index: index,
      extent: (index % 7 + 1) * 30,
    );
  },
);
```

What is `Tile` in this code? I Dont have any class or widget with that name that I can import here.
I get error - `Error: The method 'Tile' isn't defined for the class`

[image]

Comment: I think there is a property in all TextField enable by which you can enable or disable text fields based on condition.

please check this awesome answer for more

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490622/disable-a-text-edit-field-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

`Tile` used in example is from common file (you can make custom or common widgets so you can access it whenever you need)

you can find it here (*line 31 to 75*): https://github.com/letsar/flutter_staggered_grid_view/blob/master/examples/lib/common.dart

Comment: yes you are correct tile is a widget .